# Buscando documentos com mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

Estou usando o mongoDB 3.2 com Java.

Tem como salvar uma consulta do mongoDB em uma lista de objetos de uma classe minha?

Eu quero salvar a consulta diretamente em uma lista de pessoas.

```
class Pessoa{
    String nome;
    Date dataNascimento;
    String email;
}
```

Atualmente faço assim, por que é a única forma que conheço:

```
public List<Pessoa> listar() throws Exception {
    List<Pessoa> listPessoa = new ArrayList<>();

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbExemploMongo");
    FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("colecao1").find();

    for (Document document : iterable) {

        listPessoa.add(new Pessoa(
                document.getString("nome"),
                document.getDate("datanasc"),
                document.getString("email"))
        );
    }


    return listPessoa;
}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: 2 opções. use reflection para popular objeto baseado no nome dos atributos. Use um Orm que já faça isso por você. Eu preferencialmente não gosto de orms então tendo a usar data mappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso esteja usando o Spring, é possível usar o módulo de MongoDB do [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/), ou caso queira só um POJO mapper você pode usar o [morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia).

No próprio site do mongodb há diversas [opções](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/#pojo-mappers) para serem usadas.

Para não se ater à dependências, é possível fazer um *mapper* por *reflection* manualmente, definindo um serviço que tem um método que espera o tipo que vem do mongodb e mapeia para um tipo de objeto que você precisa batendo o nome do atributo da classe com o do documento do mongodb por reflection.